# Sortable drag and drop list cordova

Tags: cordova, drag-and-drop, html-lists

I would like to know if there is a plugin or a javascript library for sortable drag and drop list in cordova project. I found this kind of list for ionic

http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionList/

but I need it for cordova only.

Answer (score 0):

In my cordova application I am using [jqueryui-sortable](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/). Works good on android and iPhone.
It's pretty straight forward to use, however it requires jquery.

```
$(function() {
  $("#sortable").sortable();
});
```

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work. I have this code:

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

in case of Cordova you should call the sortable inside a function and then call it by name, not on ready!

```
function reorder(){
    $( ".sorteable" ).sortable();
 }

//do stuff
reorder();
```